# Laravel - Get the most recently created rows for a variety of IDs, from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I need a Laravel query that returns the most recently created row of various `site_id` rows please. At the moment, I have this query:

```
Score::whereIn('site_id', $sites)->where('type', 2)->select('score')->get();
```

But it's returning all of the scores for the sites, where type = 2.

At the moment, the `$sites` array only contains `1,2`, so it will exclude the site_ids that are 3 and 4.

**Database structure:**

[image: Database Structure]

My intended result that the query returns would be the following rows:

ID: 1, 2. - As in, they are the most recently created rows of the IDs within the array.

**Update:**

If I use:

```
Score::whereIn('site_id', $sites)->where('type', 2)
            ->select('score')
            ->groupBy('site_id')
            ->get();
```

a `groupBy` method, it returns the two scores that I want, but I'm not sure why it would return them? I thought it would just group all of the site's scores by site_id?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need: https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

With that you can easily do this:

```
$sites = Site::with('latestScore')->find($siteIds); // Collection
// now for each site:
$site->latestScore // what you wanted
```

however, if you want a collection of scores instead of accessing them via `site`, then use collection methods:

```
$sites = Site::with('latestScore')->find($siteIds); // Collection
$scores = $sites->pluck('latestScore') // get nested elements from collection
                ->filter() // filter out null items
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I am getting NULL returned if I `dd($sites);`. In my `Site` model, I have the following: `public function latestScore()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Score')->latest();
}`. However, If I execute `dd($siteIds), it returns 1 and 2 (the correct ones).

Comment: useing `find([1,2])` returns a collection, so if you have such rows, then it will return them for sure.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it ;) I manually put in `->find('1')` and that worked. I'm currently using `Site::where('trust_id', $trust_id)->select('id')->get();` to get the IDs. I'm unsure why that wouldn't work though? If I `dd($siteIds)`, it does show 1 and 2 in a collection.

Comment: Because passing a collection (`get`) will not work as you expect. Use `Site::where(..)->pluck('id')->all()` to get an array, tha you can pass to `find()` later on. *However* in this case you don't need that at all. Simply run `Site::where(..)->with('latestScore')->get()` and you got it all.

Comment: It works perfectly. Jarek, thank you very much. You've saved the day, again!

Answer (score 0):

I sounds to me like you just need an orderBy("created_at") chained to the end of your eloquent query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but orderBy would still return ALL of the results relating to those site_id's within the array, they would just be ordered in some way. I don't want all of the results, I just want the most recently created ones.

Comment: Ok so what is the cutoff for "recently created"? 1 hour? 1 day? You can use Carbon to easily handle dates in eloquent queries. Hope this helps.

Comment: No cut off, just the most recent one created for each site_id! If the site has 10 rows, pick the one that's been added most recently. If another site in the array has 3 rows, pick the one that's been added most recently.

Comment: Have a look at the available collection methods, particularly unique and filter. They could probably achieve what you're after. https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections

Comment: @Ben define most recent?

Comment: @NabinKunwar, the latest one that's been added. The newest one.

Comment: The closest one to now. So if you were to order them by created_at date, descending, it would pick the the top one for the site_id.